# sqlcmd for SQL Server 2012 in Windows 7

Tags: sql-server-2012, windows-7-x64, sqlcmd

I have big SQL file to run in ssms, but it gets stuck each time I try. So want to run it on sqlcmd.

Can someone help me on how can I use sqlcmd for SQL Server 2012 in Windows 7?

I checked I don't have a `Binn` folder in the following location:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I found SQLCMD.exe locates on  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn"

Or you can open dos-command prompt and use dir /s /b "SQLCMD.exe" to find it.